# react-router v4 NavLink is not changing URL

Tags: react-router, create-react-app, react-router-v4

when I started the project I did not work with create-react-app
I built the basic react-flux app like always which is with browserify and babelify and all
and the react-router v4 was working and no problem happened

then I immigrated to create-react-app env
to use the testing and building tools that is offered

and I installed all packages that I used previously properly
but react-router v4 had a problem

when I click NavLink, it does not change the URL
but when I change the URL manually it works fine

I use BrowserRouter like this:

```
    <BrowserRouter history={HashRouter}<App /></BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

And NavLink like this:

```
    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to={"/drugs"}>
                            <i className="fa fa-medkit" aria-hidden="false"/>
                            &nbsp;Drugs
                        </NavLink>
```

And Router like this:

```
   <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Patients}/>
                <Route exact path="/drugs" component={Drugs}/>
                <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
                <Route path="*" component={Error}/>
            </Switch>
```

and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your **component does not update properly**. This can happen if you inherit from `React.PureComponent` instead of `React.Component` or mess up with the method `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

If you can't figure it out (you should), you can still pass the `location` object manually with the HOC `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` like so :

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Menu = ({ location }) => (
  <menu>
    <NavLink
      className="nav-link"
      activeClassName="active"
      location={location}
      to="/drugs"
    >
      <i className="fa fa-medkit" aria-hidden="false" />
      &nbsp;Drugs
    </NavLink>
  </menu>
);

export default withRouter(Menu);
```

> Note: Most imports have been stripped out for clarity

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `<Navlink to={"/drugs"}`. When you use `{}` You're indicating that you'll be using JS, and since `"/drugs"` is not valid js it fails.

Instead remove the {}.

```
<NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/drugs">
```

Comment: it did not work :\ I tried this before and tried it again

Comment: @JihadBadran did you install `react-router-dom`? or `react-router` directly?

Comment: I installed both, NavLink is in react-router-dom after all

Comment: I removed react-router and i use only react-router-dom now

Comment: No, i just gave updates about the situation, its as it is, NavLink is not changing Url

Comment: Nothing at all :/